# state value is not modified after setState in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know setState is an async action so I have made a sync call to  make sure that state value is updated before my `componentWillReceiveProps` triggers but still it shows me previous value. this code has written in my child element. I suspect is that any thing to do in my parent element?or is there any other reason? below is my code

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

      loading: false,
      yearValue:Number(localStorage.getItem('year'))//this is 2019

    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {

  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log(
      'before if condition...',
      nextProps,
      Number(localStorage.getItem('year'))
    );
    if (
      this.state.yearValue ===
      Number(localStorage.getItem('year')) //this condition satisfied twice before it changed the value
    ) {
      console.log('inside if condition.....', nextProps);
      this.setSstate = {

        loading: false
      };
    } else this.setState({ loading: false });
  }
  updatePrograValues = year => {//year = 2017
    if (year === Number(localStorage.getItem('year'))) {
      this.props.showPlanYearValues(year);
    } else {


      this.setState({

        loading: true
      },this.props.tooltipRefresher());
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I assume the errant `;` in your `setState` call is a typo in the question and isn't in the actual code, the problem is here:

```
this.setState({
  loading: true
},this.props.tooltipRefresher());
```

That **calls** `this.props.tooltipRefresher()` and then passes its return value into `setState`, exactly the way `foo(bar())` *calls* `bar` and passes its return value into `foo`.

If you meant for it to be called after the state value is updated, remove the `()` from it so you're not *calling* it, you're passing it into `setState` so `setState` will call it when the state is set:

```
this.setState({
  loading: true
},this.props.tooltipRefresher);
// No () --------------------^
```

**If** it's sensitive to the value of `this` (e.g., `tooltipRefresher` expects `this` to be `this.props`), you may need `bind`:

```
this.setState({
  loading: true
},this.props.tooltipRefresher.bind(this.props));
```

...or an arrow function:

```
this.setState({
  loading: true
},() => this.props.tooltipRefresher());
```

Comment: Sorry can you please elaborate it  more. you meant to say whatever I am returning from `tooltipRefresher` is going back to state?

Comment: You need to pass a function to setState, which will be called after the state is updated and the component is rerendered. Currently, you are passing the value which is returned by the function tooltipRefresher, because you are actually calling it. If you removed the parenthesis, you would be passing the actual function and your problem would be fixed.

Comment: oohh..I seriously need to look when to use bind and when not to

Comment: Well, all binding does is it sets `this` inside the function to the value you passed to the `bind` function. If you really need to set `this` to the current component inside tooltipRefresher, you would need to do `this.props.tooltipRefresher.bind(this)`, not `this.params`.

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to offer the arrow function solution to OPs question. It's far more straightforward and pretty pervasive within the React community for callbacks. `() => this.props.tooltipRefresher()`